# What does misplaced apprehension entail?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

For listeners, you need not to fear all such apprehensions are misplaced—there will be no indifference in the national grid?

Comment: Were some people worried that there might be indifference in the national grid?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Please provide your research for "misplaced apprehension"

Comment: *misplaced apprehension = **fears that turned out to be unjustified***

Comment: It’s something like ... well, it’s nothing; don’t worry about it.