# In what context is 'misplaced apprehension' used?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The phrase is said in the backdrop that the power grid is robust and strong while those who believe in a potential indifference in the grid are dispensed as harbouring 'misplaced apprehension'.

Comment: Might you mean dismissed not dispensed?

Comment: Duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/530481/what-does-misplaced-apprehension-entail - you were told what the phrase meant.

Answer (score 1):

Misplaced apprehension as in unwarranted anxiety

It means that they're worrying for no good reason. That their fears are unfounded.